# I need to add a verification TXT DNS record in cPanel, but only have A, MX and CNAME as alternatives

Tags: dns, cpanel

I am setting up a Google account for a new domain, and Google requires me to add a verification TXT DNS record. 
I have the domain at cPanel, and when going to the zone editor, I only find the options for A, MX, and CNAME. I see no TXT option. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Zone editor, click on Manage option next to the domain name.
2. Click On Add record.

Now you should be able to choose the TXT record from the record type column. It will be something link this.

[TXT record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayZO2.png)

If you do not have that option, then contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable the "Zone Editor (AAAA, CAA, SRV, TXT)" feature "WHM Home »Packages »Feature Manager »Edit Feature List"

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer helped me to find that the domain manager was different than the domain owner. There I was.